# Google line charts how to NOT interpolate missing data

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a database table with a series of events, these events have dates for when they happen. Now I would like to display the number of events for each month and show them in a line chart.
I get the data via php and generate the js-code in a loop using data.addrow

Now this works fine, but if there is a month with no events it will not be added as a row and the line will simply interpolate the missing month.
So for example january 5 events, february 0 and march 5 events, would create a horizontal line going from january to march making it look like there where 5 events in february.

How can i make the line go down to zero for a "empty" month?

Do I need to fill in empty rows/months with null? This would not seem very practical.

Comment: There are several ways you might have implemented the line chart with date values.  Could you provide an example that demonstrates the problem, either in jsfiddle or provide a drawVisualization function that works in the GViz playground: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the line to go down to zero, you are interpolating, just in a different way. Google gives you two ways to deal with empty values (nulls) using the [`interpolateNulls`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) option:

1. *True* will guess what value belongs in between (the current behavior in your chart)
2. *False* will leave a break in the line for empty data points (not what you want)

To get all null values to show as zero, you would need to go through your data with a for loop and change any null value to 0. Something like the below code.

```
for (i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  if ( data.getValue(1, i) == null )
    data.setValue(1, i) = 0
}
```

The above code isn't tested, and I don't know how your data is set up so I didn't spend much time testing it (I have no idea how many columns, etc. your data has, you can adjust and test as needed).