# Multiple continues lines with unmatching x-values leaves gaps in graph

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Im using Google Chart to visualize date-values pairs. Not all values exist for all dates, so I expected to fill in with nulls. But that leaves gaps in the chart (red line):

[image]

How do I get a line chart without any jumps?

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['x', 'Cats', 'Blanket 1', 'Blanket 2'],
          [new Date(2012),   1,       1,           0.5],
          [new Date(2013),   1,       1,           0.5],
          [new Date(2014),   2,       null,         1],
          [new Date(2015),   4,       2,           0.5],
          [new Date(2016),   4,       3,           0.5],
        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                        width: 500, height: 400,
                        vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
                );
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Related (this should solve your issue): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998545/google-line-charts-how-to-not-interpolate-missing-data/16006039#16006039

Comment: Alternatively, you can leave them null and set the `interpolateNulls` option to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jmac! Swapping out null with true is exactly what I needed: http://jsfiddle.net/nf9wG/

> ```
>       ['x', 'Cats', 'Blanket 1', 'Blanket 2'],
>       [new Date(2012),   1,       1,           0.5],
>       [new Date(2013),   1,       1,           0.5],
>       [new Date(2014),   2,       true,         1],
>       [new Date(2015),   4,       2,           0.5],
>       [new Date(2016),   4,       3,           0.5],
> ```